# how to open an address from a link

Tags: html

I wanted to create a link on my page where I simply wanna open www.google.com from my site.

I have the tag like this:
`<a target='_blank' href='www.google.com'>`  and it is opening this link `http://localhost:78/efm/efm21/www.google.com`

I read some articles where they say to use ../ to go back one directory in my case i had to move ../../../ in order to reach only www.google.com to be opened by i still stuck on it, it opens `localhost:78/www.google.com.`

My question is how come I open directly www.google.com from the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must specify the full path, relative to the protocol or higher.

```
<a href="//www.google.com/">link</a>
or
<a href="http://www.google.com/">link</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add protocol http://

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the protocol, otherwise the browser will try to open a file called `www.google.com` on your site.

You have two options.

**#1:**

`<a href="//www.google.com" target="_blank">` will open Google with the same protocol of your site, e.g.

```
https://example.com
```

will open

```
https://www.google.com
```

and
    http://example.com
will open

```
http://www.google.com
```

.

**#2:**

`<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">` or `<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">` will open Google with `HTTP` or `HTTPS`, unaffected by the protocol of your site.